# How do i create a 'layer' in between my router and a user connecting to it

Tags: networking, router, hardware, wifi, gateway

Like when you go to starbucks the first thing you see if you go to their wifi is "Welcome to starbucks, please accept our terms". Or also at most airports, it makes it impossible to surf until you accept their terms.

Furthermore, what is this called? Is it possible to order routers with this pre-loaded on it, and how would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term for what you want is "captive portal".  You can purchase devices that'll do it out of the box, for quite eye-watering amounts of money, or build your own with various Linux distributions specifically designed for such things.

Comment: Can you expand on an example of the cost? I would need a lot of them,and not something I would want to package and do up myself for each one.

Comment: And my final question is, is it possible to perhaps buy a router and 3rd party software and get the same effect, or does the router itself need to be modified by someone experienced first?

Comment: pretty sure DDWRT has a flavor for this, take a look into that.

Comment: @Tallboy: I understand that you may not have known the correct terminology for the technology you want but having found out what it is couldn't you do a bit of research yourself ?

Comment: I already tried and understood zero about what it was talking about...

Comment: If you didn't understand anything you were reading about captive portals, you may want to hire a consultant who does. Otherwise you're in WAY over your head with the kind of IT knowledge you sound like you'd need if you're deploying this in many sites.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a captive portal. There are many open source and free solutions available.

Cisco has some solutions as well, they are not cheap.